# Compile Razor Views in MonoDevelop at Build Time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, monodevelop

How to compile Razor Views in Monodevelop 4.2, to get the Errors in the Views while developing? I have tried setting **MvcBuildViews** to **true**. But that seems to be not working in Monodevelop.